# Mockito matcher and array of primitives

Tags: java, mockito

With Mockito, I want to `verify()` a method call with `byte[]` in its argument list, but I didn't find how to write this.

```
 myMethod( byte[] )
```

I just want something like `anyByteArray()`, how to do that with Mockito ?

Comment: Do you really not care what the contents of the byte array are?

I see this a lot in unit testing, where people use anyX() matchers because they're convenient, but realistically you almost always should care what's being passed in. If you're not using an Answer that actually consumes the value, you probably should match on an actual expected argument.

Comment: @Matunos: That's debatable. Using the any-matchers can make tests simpler and the next person looking at the test will not be distracted by unnecessarily precise matching and can focus on the actual purpose of the test.

Comment: @tbruelle: Please keep in mind that every array in Java is an object. That would help you at the begining.

Answer (score 560, accepted):

I would try `any(byte[].class)`

Comment: If you want to verify a specific byte[] you can use `AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(expectedArray)`

Comment: Or Matchers.<byte[]>any().

Comment: thank you so much JohnOxley, I just couldn't work out why the normal `eq` wasn't working for an int array.

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 49):

Try this:

```
AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(array);
```

Answer (score 16):

I would rather use `Matchers.<byte[]>any()`. This worked for me.

Comment: Warning for everybody: Now is deprecated so I'd go for the voted answer Mockito.any(byte[].class)

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Mutanos and Alecio.
Further, one can check as many identical method calls as possible (verifying the subsequent calls in the production code, the order of the verify's does not matter).
Here is the code:

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.*;

    verify(mockObject).myMethod(aryEq(new byte[] { 0 }));
    verify(mockObject).myMethod(aryEq(new byte[] { 1, 2 }));
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `Matchers.refEq` for this.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me was `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.isA`

for example:

```
isA(long[].class)
```

that works fine.

the implementation difference of each other is:

```
public static <T> T any(Class<T> type) {
    reportMatcher(new VarArgAware(type, "<any " + type.getCanonicalName() + ">"));
    return Primitives.defaultValue(type);
}

public static <T> T isA(Class<T> type) {
    reportMatcher(new InstanceOf(type));
    return Primitives.defaultValue(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito.any()  when arguments are arrays also.
I used it like this:

```
verify(myMock, times(0)).setContents(any(), any());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a custom Matcher using `argThat`

```
Mockito.verify(yourMockHere).methodCallToBeVerifiedOnYourMockHere(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        YourTypeHere[] yourArray = (YourTypeHere[]) argument;
        // Do whatever you like, here is an example:
        if (!yourArray[0].getStringValue().equals("first_arr_val")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Writing a custom matcher, when Mockito is capable of handling this use case is only adding technical debt.

Comment: In my use case, I needed to match an array, of which it was not possible to know the order. I could not find a Mockito matcher which matched arrays _order agnostic_, for this case I found the `argThat(ArgumentMatcher<int[]>` worked well and didn't add much complexity.

Comment: Maybe useful in cases where you want to verify the first few bytes, etc...